# Can't add a new user into database using an extended PHP class

Tags: php, oop

I am still learning from online course about PHP OOP I have an exercise about inheritance, that wants to extend a connection class into a new class to add new data to db.

This is the connection.php class:

```
<?php
class connectionClass
{
    private $db_host, $db_name, $db_user;
    private $db_pass;
    private $connection;

    function __construct($host = "localhost", $name="userDB", $user = "root", $pass="igts")
    {
        $this->db_host = $host;
        $this->db_name = $name;
        $this->db_user = $user;
        $this->db_pass = $pass;
    }

    public function connect()
    {
        $this->connection = new PDO("mysql:host={$this->db_host};dbname={$this->db_name}", $this->db_user, $this->db_pass);
        $this->connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        return $this->connection;
    }
}
?>
```

And here it is the new class:

```
<?php
include('connection.php');
class insertUser extends connectionClass
{
    public $msg;
    private $connection;
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->connection = $this->connect();
    }

    public function insert_user($user, $pass, $date)
    {

            $sql = "INSERT INTO login(user_name, user_pass, date_in) VALUES(:user, :pass, :date_in)";
            $insert = $this->connection->prepare($sql);
            $insert->bindValue(':user', $user);
            $insert->bindValue(':pass', $hashed);
            $insert->bindValue(':date_in', $date);
            $insert->execute();
            header("Location: index.php");
        }

}

?>
```

And I am getting when adding a user:

> Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[3D000]:
>   Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected'

Comment: `try/catch` your connection attempt. It's failing. You're also best to call `parent::__construct()` to ensure the extended classes' `__construct` method is called. Which seems to be what you require.

Comment: thanks it works with parent::